# What is the difference between words "gadget" and "device"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

Words "gadget" and "device" are translated the same in my language. What is the difference between these words in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Gadget is less formal and can only refer to a physical object.

A smartphone is an electronic *device* but a mother might chide her child for using "that gadget" too much. Saying *gadget* in this instance is informal and even derogatory.

Other than being less formal, the word "gadget" is interchangeable with "device" when referring to a physical object.

However, "device" can refer to abstract things while gadget can't: a "plot device" is a literary term for something that advances a story's plot. A person can also be "left to his/her own devices" which is an idiom that means "left to do whatever he or she wants without help."

Gadget can't be used in these examples.

Comment: In film and TV drama plots, a "McGuffin" is a plot device, which can be a physical device, that serves no other purpose than to advance the plot. I think the "flux capacitor" in "Back to the Future" is a McGuffin.